# Does google always downrank pages with hidden texts

Tags: seo, google, hidden-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are temporarily hidden elements bad for search-engine rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11256/are-temporarily-hidden-elements-bad-for-search-engine-rankings)

I'm creating a FAQ for my page. To help the user to get a better overview I want to hide all answers and only display the questions. If the user clicks on a question the answer is set to display:block.

I know that google also reads and indexes hidden content, but I also know that hiding text is a common technique for spammers and thus probably discredited by google, resulting in getting wiped from search results.

But I'm wondering; Does google always downrank pages that have large amounts of hidden text? Does Google have some kind of intelligence? I mean an FAQ like this is not that uncommon. Should I not use this kind of FAQ?

Comment: I think it should be okay judging from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css
; When in doubt, do an AB-test.